# Filter a ruby array based on values in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, select

I have an array of extensions and an array of file names:

```rb
exts = ['.zip', '.tgz', '.sql']
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.doc', 'file2.tgz', 'file3.sql', 'file6.foo', 'file4.zip']
```

I want to filter the file names by one or more matching extensions.  In this case, the result would be:

```rb
["file1.zip", "file2.tgz", "file3.sql", "file4.zip"]
```

I know I can do this with a nested loop:

```rb
exts.each_with_object([]) do |ext, arr|
    files.each do |file| 
        arr << entry if file.include?(ext)
    end
end
```

This feels ugly to me.  With select, I can avoid the feeling of nested loops:

```rb
files.select { |file| exts.each { |ext| file.include?(ext) } }
```

This works and feels better.  Is there still a more elegant way that I'm missing?

Comment: Where do the entries in `files` come from? If you are filtering files in a directory, [`Dir.glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Dir.html#glob-method) could be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, they do come from a glob, and that’s the approach I use – this is just an example.

Comment: FWIW, it’s a helpful reminder that a matching via a glob would probably be a better approach for this specific case. I probably could have used a more generic example to suit the question.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`Enumerable#grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) with a regexp like this:

```
exts = ['.zip', '.tgz', '.sql']
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.doc', 'file2.tgz', 'file3.sql', 'file6.foo', 'file4.zip']

files.grep(/#{Regexp.union(exts)}$/)
#=> ["file2.tgz", "file3.sql", "file4.zip"]
```

I use `Regexp.union` instead of a simple `exts.join('|')` because `exts` include dots (`.`) which have a special meaning in regular expressions. `Regexp.union` escapes those dots automatically.

Comment: Thanks! It’s funny you mention this – I had added grep as a potential path I could take, but I missed the regex piece here. I think this is really clean.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it a bit further, I realized I could make the `select` better if I changed the logic slightly:

```rb
exts = ['zip', 'tgz', 'sql']
files.select{ |file| exts.include?(file) }
```

As far as I can tell, this is as clean as I can get.

Comment: I think it would be more clear if you wrote `exts = ['zip', 'tgz', 'sql']`. Then `files.select { |f| exts.any? { |ext| f.end_with?(ext) } }` or `files.select { |f| exts.any? { |ext| File.extname(f) == ext } }`.

Comment: Thanks, I did mean `files`. I agree that adding the extensions array to this example would make it more clear. `any?` I knew, but `end_with?` was new to me; thanks for that. This suggestion is very readable. I think you ought to add this as a possibility answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you store extensions in a set, you'll reduce the runtime complexity from O(NM) to O(N).

```rb
exts = ['.zip', '.tgz', '.sql'].to_set
files.select { |file| exts.include?(File.extname(file)) }
```